# Change Memo1.Font of all Dynamically Created Forms on Delphi

Tags: delphi

I create many forms on runtime using

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);
Form2.Show;
```

Now I need to change the Memo1.Font of them at once.

```
Form2.Memo1.Font:=newfont;
```

But only the latest created form's Memo1.Font changes. How can I change all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you're calling `Application.CreateForm(TForm2, Form2);` multiple times which reassigns the newly created form to your global `Form2` variable, so later when you refer to `Form2` you're referring to the last-created instance.

To access all instances of `TForm2` in your application, you can use [`Screen.Forms`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Forms) property:

```
for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  if Screen.Forms[I] is TForm2 then
    TForm2(Screen.Forms[I]).Memo1.Font := ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is, that component names should be unique,
You can not address multiple components by just **one** name!

In this case You will have to iterate through all components to find all TMemos.
This could look something like

```
var i,j: integer;
begin
  // first find all Forms in Application
  for i:=0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Application.Components[i] is TForm then
    begin
      with (Application.Components[i] as TForm) do
      begin
        // now find all TMemos and change the font
        for j:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
        begin
          if (Components[j] is TMemo) and (Components[j].Name = 'Memo1')  then (Components[j] as TMemo).Font.Name := 'Arial';
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

This is a very general approach and You can easily adapt it to other components within Your application.

Another approach would be to memorize all created TMemos in an Objectlist when they are created the first time (then You could easily iterate the object list and change TMemos properties) but without knowing more about Your implementation it is hard to give a good advice.

Comment: This will affect all memos on all forms but the question states the goal is only to change `Memo1.Font` on instances of `TForm2`.

Comment: Even for a more generic solution, I would prefer to use `Screen.Forms` instead of `Application.Components`; it's more specific and skips unnecessary other components like data modules.

Comment: Right. So I wrote. This is a general approach and shows how to iterate and search for components within an application. I didn't give him a fish, I gave him an fishing rod. When he understands this concept, he can help himself by his next similar problem.